# Draw two lines and drop one line using ggplot2 using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following data

```
df<-data.frame( c(63.5, 64, 64.5, 65, 65.5, 66, 66.5), c(0.8,0.8,0.5,0.5,0.5,0,0))

colnames(df)<-c("age", "labor_force_participation")

df$pensionbreak<-cut(df$age,
                     breaks = c(-Inf, 64.4,65.5,Inf),
                     labels = c("prior pension", "transition area", "after pension"))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(age, labor_force_participation, colour=pensionbreak))

p + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  xlab("age") + 
  ylab("fraction of males working") + 
  labs(color = "Retirement") + 
  theme_bw()
```

The above data and graph shows labor force participation prior and after receving pension benefits (around the age of 65). As you can see the graphs has three lines, namely 1) prior pension, 2) transition area, and 3) after pension. The transition area is there as not everyone gets exactly pension benefits at age 65 (some claim it a little bit earlier, others a little bit later).

Now I would like to keep the lines for prior pension and after pension, but I only want to keep the data points in the transition area. So in other words, I would like to keep the red line (prior pension) and the blue line (after pension) and I only would like to 1) keep the dots in the transition area but 2) have no line present there. Could someone explain to me how I should alter my code to get this. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give different subset of data to each layer:

```
p + 
  geom_point(data = subset(df, pensionbreak == "transition area")) + 
  geom_smooth(
    data = subset(df, pensionbreak != "transition area"),
    method = "lm", se = TRUE
  ) +
  xlab("age") + 
  ylab("fraction of males working") + 
  labs(color = "Retirement") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want to specify which color is which, use `scale_color_manual`.